# file not found for localhost sub-domain nginx wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

In the browser, I get "File not found". Server log and configuration are provided. I'm really not sure what to do at this point.

The Error:

> 2018/04/24 14:00:46 [error] 28717#28717: *9 FastCGI sent in stderr:
>   "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream,
>   client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", 
>   upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "wasob.localhost"

wasob.localhost

```
server { 

  #Nginx should listen on port 80 for requests to yoursite.com
  listen 80; 
  server_name wasob.localhost; 

  #Create access and error logs in /var/log/nginx
  access_log /var/log/nginx/default.access_log; 
  error_log /var/log/nginx/wasob.error_log error; 

  root /var/www/html/wasob/;
  #The homepage of your website is a file called index.php 
  index index.php; 

   location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ index.php
    }

  #Specifies that Nginx is looking for .php files
  location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    #if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
    #    return 404;
    #}

    fastcgi_index index.php;

    # SCRIPT_FILENAME parameter is used for PHP FPM determining
    #  the script name. If it is not set in fastcgi_params file,
    # i.e. /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params or in the parent contexts,
    # please comment off following line:
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

     # Mitigate https://httpoxy.org/ vulnerabilities
    fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";

     # include the fastcgi_param setting
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  }


}
```

The error and config are available at https://gist.github.com/skinuxgeek/4d4f86490f87805d1781782670551db9

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What's the internal URL of the file and the URL you are using on the browser?

Comment: silly question, but still: there is an index.php in `/var/www/html/wasob/`?

Comment: The URL would be http://wasob.localhost/ and yes, wordpress has index.php

Comment: And the web root is /var/www/html/wasob

Comment: You have a typo in your `try_files` statement - it should be `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;` - you are missing a leading `/` and a terminating `;`. Check the configuration using `nginx -T`